# How the row wise calculation made in the C# wpf?

Tags: c#

In the following image the opening balance of the each row is:

- the sum of the above column if it is credit
- the minus of the above column if it is debit

How can it be done in c#

[image]

For example:

```
    credit    debit    OpenBal
 1.   100  -     0   -   100
 2.    90  -     0   -   190
 3.   100  -     0   -   290
 4.     0  -    50   -   240
 5.     0  -   100   -   140
 6.   150  -     0   -   290
```

Comment: You need to give us something to work with (code!). Show us some effort on your part. We are not going to write your programs for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, depending on when/how/where the values should be calculated.

The following example demonstrates how you could realize the calculation in a very simple case when the OpenBalance is calculated directly after the data is loaded und you don't have to refresh the OpenBalance:

#### "Load" data:

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add( "credit", typeof( decimal ) );
tbl.Columns.Add( "debit", typeof( decimal ) );
tbl.Columns.Add( "OpenBal", typeof( decimal ) );

tbl.Rows.Add( 100, 0 );
tbl.Rows.Add( 90, 0 );
tbl.Rows.Add( 100, 0 );
tbl.Rows.Add( 0, 50 );
tbl.Rows.Add( 0, 100 );
tbl.Rows.Add( 150, 0 );
```

#### Calculate Open Balance:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    var row = tbl.Rows[i];
    if ( i == 0 )
        row["OpenBal"] = (decimal)row["credit"] - (decimal)row["debit"];
    else
    {
        var previousRow = tbl.Rows[i-1];
        row["OpenBal"] = (decimal)previousRow["OpenBal"] + ( decimal)row["credit"] - (decimal)row["debit"];
    }
}
```